# Intent is not working for onClick method

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use an intent in an onClick method of a checkbox, but I get the error that the method startActivity is undefined and that the constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener ect..) is undefined as well. Here is my code:

```
        final CheckBox addCheckbox = (CheckBox) v
            .findViewById(R.id.addCheckbox);

    // set data to display

    addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                                    .getApplicationIcon(entry.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon


                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(this, GridView.class);
                                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                                this.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are inside of a `listener`, `this` refers to the `listener` which is why you get the error

> "the method startActivity is undefined"

Simply remove `this`

```
startActivity(intent);
```

That is the same reason for the other error

> the constructor
>   Intent(new View.OnClickListener ect..)"

Use the `View`s `Context` that was clicked which will be the `Activity Context`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridView.class);
```

So that block will look like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridView.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ClassName.this.startActivity??

Comment: @hasan I can see how it would seem so but, no it is not needed. It uses the Activities Context in this situation. The Intent constructor needs a Context explicitly defined here so that is why you need to provide it

Comment: Ok thank you. The first part worked (with using the Views Context), but I still have the error that "startActivity(intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener"

Comment: @user2909006 You can try changing it to `v.getContext().startActivity(intent);` but you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Repalce your code with below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YOURACTIVITY_NAME.this, GridView.class);

intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);

 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `v.getContext()` is a better practice than `YOURACTIVITY_NAME.this` and will return the same `Context` in this situation.